# gulp-print in Powershell is empty

Tags: powershell, gulp

I have a simple gulp task that just prints some .js files. In cmd it prints fine but in Powershell gulp-print is empty. Any pointers on why that is? Here is the gulpfile.js and the outputs.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpprint = require('gulp-print');

gulp.task('print', function() {
    gulp.src('./src/**/*.js').pipe(gulpprint());
});
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you try to mark the lines in PowerShell? It almost looks like the piped output is written to the host with the same Foreground Color as the Background

Comment: I've seen the exact thing @MathiasR.Jessen suggests several times using gulp and powershell so that's a likely culprit.

Comment: Yes, the content is there when I cut out a big section and pasted it notepad. I tried a light color background and sure enough it's there. Tried a custom formatter with a different color and that works too: I wonder what is the best way to fix this without adding the custom formatter to each print?

Comment: I looked at the gulp-print GitHub and there is supposed to be a way to disable the color but it isn't working. However, in  gulp-print.js I changed magenta = colors.magenta to magenta = colors.white and it's working. Quite sure it isn't an ideal solution as it will be overwritten by an update and someone smarter will suggest something better but it works for now.

Comment: Selecting the lines does not reveal the filenames (gulp-print). Only the time is present.

Answer (score 1):

it's not ideal but you can disable colors

```
gulp --no-colors print
```

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation about `--no-colors`. I couldn't find it & it did not work either.